# How to pass caret sign (^) to the selenium web driver send_keys() method

Tags: python, selenium

I am doing automated tests with python and selenim web driver and need to login to website using complex password.

I need to pass any special charecters including caret sign (^) to the send_keys method but it doesn't work.

For example I try to supply the following password to the method: `45pEq8wfIj^K`

The send_keys method will send following: `45pEq8wfIjK` (the caret sign is ommited)

I have tried to put the caret sign into curly braces and supply it to the method like `{^}` but the result were empty curly braces `{}`. Also tried escape sign and raw string = not a solution.

I have tried the solution provided by ou_ryperd and this seems to work, but I still experience the following problem:

I wrote the following code which works:

```
if "^" in password:
    splitString = re.split(r"^", password)
    user_field.send_keys(splitString[0])
    user_field.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + '6')
    user_field.send_keys(splitString[1])
```

This works fine (only with one caret sign obviously) as I get the caret sign passed to the send_keys method correctly now.

But for some reason, there is one additional caret sign ^ before the first part of the string?! Any idea why this happens?

i.e. for the following password `45pEq8wfIj\^K`

I get `^45pEq8wfIj\^K`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send a key chord:

```
    .send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + '6')
```

Comment: This seems to be a good approach but I have two problems: 1. I need to input a whole password so I need to switch from string charecters to the Keys and then continue with string - any idea how to implement this? 2. I am using german keybord and there is ampersand & located for SHIFT + 6. Caret sign ^ can be reached by ALT GR + the first Key on the left side of the keybord below Esc. Also hard to implement this for me...

Comment: I would start off by asking the developers to relax the password for test automation. If the won't, or if the object of the test is to test the complex password, you will have to code a routine that passes the password into a set of send_keys statements. You will have to be creative with your code, which is part of the fun of test automation :-)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As I need to find the solution for doing this, I have been working on first code prototype which brought me further but still has problem. I have edited my question and put the code there. Now I get one additional caret sign at the beginning of the string. Any idea why this happens?